# Error message: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated."

Tags: smtpclient, system.net.mail

I have searched other posts and set required things in my gmail account(https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

but somehow it still throws exception with the message "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveAppointment(Appointment mdl)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "mypass");
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                //Setting From , To and CC
                mail.From = new MailAddress("username@gmail.com", "MyWeb Site");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("username@gmail.com"));

                smtpClient.Send(mail);

                return View();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

What should it be I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx) and code (because there could be no matching `EnableSsl` in the configuration file. 
You may also need to enable access for "less secure apps" in your gmail settings page. [here](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/)
This is necessary if you are getting the exception "`The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Then below code should works.

```
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        client.Send("username@gmail.com", "username@gmail.com", "subject", "body");
```